# COMDAT section placement in the executable

Tags: visual-c++, linker

Visual C++ project, Wintel-32. I have a C file that's compiled to object then linked, pretty vanilla setup. Debug configuration.

When I examine the object file with `dumpbin /symbols`, it tells me that my object file has numerous code ("COMDAT") sections - one per function, it seems. They all are named `.text`, and linker would unite them into the one large .text section in the final executable.

Function-level linking is disabled in project settings. I'm not even sure why are COMDAT's being generated in the first place.

But I've noticed in the debugger that those OBJ-level sections (functions) are not going contiguously in the executable. Between them there's some padding - several dozen bytes of `int 3` instruction - obviously dead space where control is not supposed to go. The function boundaries are all aligned by 16 bytes, but there's more going on - this isn't just alignment by 16 bytes, or the padding would be much less in most cases. It's typically around 20-40 bytes, but I've seen some outliers - 11 bytes padding here, 73 there.

This has nothing to do with linker's /ALIGN option - that one deals with sections proper. And its default is 4K, definitely not what we have here.

Why this padding? And what's the algorithm for its size (definitely not mere alignment)?

Comment: Do you have Edit & Continue turned on for this project?

Comment: Point taken. Replaced /ZI with /Zi, COMDAT's went away. Make an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Edit & Continue turned on for the project, the padding you're seeing is introduced so the compiler and linker can patch the executable image rather than having to rebuild and relink it.